# IBM Watson Assistant: How to close dialog by disabling input field?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant, input-field

How can I disable the input field of Watson assistant after giving closing statement?

Ex: If the bot shows thank you for using our services, then the Input field should be grayed out and should not let user to type, user has to restart the bot to chat.

Comment: Do you mean in the web chat, in any other integration or where? What is with follow-up questions?

Comment: In any integration, if the bot displays closing statement, then it should disable the input field. But primarily, I want to know in web chat integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in watson :instance.updateAssistantInputFieldVisibility(false) it disables the input field, so you can customize the way you want to use.

Comment: For reference please visit : https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-instance-methods#updateAssistantInputFieldVisibility

Answer (score 0):

I see the following options for you to "disable" the chat in Watson Assistant.

- You could [respond with a pause](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview#dialog-overview-add-pause).
- Set an internal variable that from your point of view the dialog is done and should not be resumed again. React to any input by not answering.
- Consider a special version of [anything_else](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-start#dialog-start-anything-else).
- Build your own interface that can disable the input.

IMHO disabling input should not be done, it is against best practices. You want the user to interact. Reloading the web page with the chat typically reenables input anyway. So what is the use case...?

Comment: I am not using any custom interface for the chatbot, using the default integration setup provided by Watson assistant. The main use case is :by disabling the input field, I can call an api to store the conversation into database which will make me understand that user has reached the end of conversation and I can call an API to store the conversation into database, if I leave the input field open, the customer will type something and there won't be any end to it.  Increasing the pause, anything_else does not seem to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: by disabling input, you decide to close the dialog :) - disabling the input field can be done using a custom integration. The above are your options as far as I see it. Please mark answered...

Comment: Yes, that is what I've been asking, and I want to know if that can be done using watson assistant integration.

Comment: if by integration you say "pre-defined": no, it is not best practice and not available. If you mean, if it is possible with WA: yes, but you have to customize it

Comment: Seems like this works, https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-instance-methods#updateAssistantInputFieldVisibility